# The import org.eclipse no pudo ser resuelto

Tags: eclipse, maven, importación

He clonado un proyecto Maven Java que utiliza Ecore en EMF (Eclipse Modelling Framework). En dicho proyecto obtengo el error "The import org.eclipse could not be resolved" en todos los archivos Java que tienen ese import.

Por ejemplo:

```
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;
```

He revisado El Java Build Path y apunta al JDK que tengo instalado en mi sistema (17).

He utilizado el EMF para otros proyectos SOLO con Ecore y me ha funcionado correctamente.

Las dependencias del archivo pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans/yamlbeans -->
        <!-- 1.14 version is not available in Maven Central Repository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>yamlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

¿Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

Al lanzar una nueva instancia en Eclipse obtengo lo siguiente en la terminal:

```
If I try to launch the project as a new Eclipse project I get this in the console, but it works:
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.foreign
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
!SESSION 2023-11-21 11:55:39.749 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.29.0.20230907-1200
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product -data C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Julio\Master\Segundo Curso\TFM/../runtime-New_configuration -dev file:C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/Julio/Master/Segundo Curso/TFM/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/New_configuration/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2023-11-21 11:55:49.566
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2023-11-21 11:55:49.567
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type"),
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler("org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace"),
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2023-11-21 11:55:57.867
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Hp'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

La instancia se lanza correctamente.

Comment: puedes poner una línea de import que esté fallando?

Comment: Claro.

Una línea de ejemplo: **import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;**

Básicamente fallan todas las líneas que contengan "import org.eclipse..."

Comment: ¿Eclipse se ha descargado las dependencias? Prueba a ejecutar `mvn compile` manualmente.

Comment: ¿Dónde ejecuto ese comando? Perdón soy nuevo en proyectos Maven. 

He comprobado además que tengo todo el pack M2E instalado y actualizado

Comment: gracias, @JulioEscuderoCuesta como puede ver la clase de ese import está disponible dentro del jar con la versión 2.29.0 https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList

Comment: Muchas gracias!! @PabloLozano metiendo los jar en el proyecto ya me funciona. Aún así, he estado investigando y, ¿debería tratar estas dependencias directamente en el archivo pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas Maven en un proyecto, siempre hay un fichero pom.xml en la raíz del mismo que declara (entre otras muchas cosas) las dependencias del mismo.
En este caso específico, tienes tres dependencias que son del grupo `org.eclipse.emf`.

¿Qué significa esto? Que a la hora de generar el JAR/WAR de dicho proyecto, Maven descargará de su repositorio de versiones dichas dependencias en un directorio de tu máquina (generalmente en un directorio llamado `.m2` que está en tu "home" (En Linux es `/home/<usuario>`, en Mac/Windows en `/Users/<usuario>`).

Eclipse creo que viene con Maven incluido, pero siempre es buena idea instalarlo en tu sistema para poder ejecutarlo desde la línea de comandos (en un terminal, te sitúas en el directorio raíz de tu proyecto y ejecutas `mvn compile`, o `mvn test`)

Comment: Como has dicho @PabloLozano, en mi archivo pom.xml tengo 3 dependencias del grupo `org.eclipse.emf`. No obstante, las clases Java dentro del mismo proyecto presentan el error _The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved_ y solo desaparece cuando incorporo las librerías JAR al proyecto como externas.